# compile error with msg file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I keep getting an error that ROS can't find the messages which the message I am trying to publish from my executable depends on. The compiler suggests that maybe I forgot to specify them in generate_messages() but I did. Here is a copy of my CMakeLists.txt. Any help will be appreciated.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(uuv_words)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS message_generation roscpp 
std_msgs turtlesim)
add_message_files(FILES away.msg)
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs roscpp turtlesim)
catkin_package(
  INCLUDE_DIRS ##include
  LIBRARIES ${PROJECT_NAME}
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp message_runtime std_msgs turtlesim
  ##DEPENDS system_lib
 )
include_directories(${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(away src/away.cpp) 
add_dependencies(away uuv_words_generate_messages_cpp)
target_link_libraries(away ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/98146/compile-error-with-msg-file/) by [ayslegacy](https://answers.ros.org/users/8471/ayslegacy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your CMakeLists.txt is very disordered, but I think that the generate_messages() command is missing.
If your message away.msg depends on other messages (for example std_msgs) you should tell catkin in a similar way:

```
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Tirjen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7761/tirjen/) with karma: 808 on 2013-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0